# How much JavaScript/CSS knowledge does a parser need to parse HTML?

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing

If a browser encounters

```
<script>
let xyz = '<b>Bold text</b>';
</script>
```

It does not put `b` tags inside the `script` element of the DOM. This implies some sort of special-casing in the browser's parsing logic which knows to ignore HTML. Somehow, though, the browser knows to return to standard HTML-parsing at the closing script tag. Similarly, HTML in an inline `<style>` does not enter the DOM.

What logic is used here, and does it require knowledge of the (ever-evolving) JS syntax rules? Are there tags other than `script` and `style` where similar logic is needed?

Comment: How the HTML source in the question gets parsed by (conforming) HTML parsers has nothing to do with the parser knowing anything at all about JavaScript. Instead the parser just follows the HTML parsing algorithm in the HTML spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing

Comment: Specifically in this case, the parser follows the parts of the algorithm that start with it being in the “script data state” https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#script-data-state and then staying in that sate until switching briefly into the “script data less-than sign state” https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#script-data-less-than-sign-state when it finds the first `<` in the `let xyz = '<b>Bold text</b>';` line, but quickly switching back to the script data state when it finds no `/` after that `<`.

Comment: Those steps cause the `<b>Bold text` in that line to get consumed as ordinary text instead of as markup tokens. Then it gets to the `</`, switches a couple times but  again switches back to the script data state when instead of finding `script` after that `</`, it finds `b`.

It only fully switches back out from that script-data-state cycle after it finds the `</script>` end tag.

The entry point for all this is the part of *The "in head" insertion mode* https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inhead section that’s labeled **A start tag whose tag name is "script"**